# R- how to plot cumulative lines

Tags: r, plot, statistics, histogram, cumulative-sum

my problem is the following:

I have to plot a curve which shows the number of breakdowns (y) by the service life (x) but in a cumulative way - and that's the point where I struggle!!

The solution is given in the second Picture, my code in the first (I think only the type of the plot should be different)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld9BL.png)
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgsqD.png)

Thanks so much for every help!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your data, so this is more of a comment, then a complete solution.

```
n <- sum(h$counts)          # This should sum up to the number of observations
y <- cumsum(h$counts) / n   # Your y values
x <- h$mids                   # I assume these to be your x-axis value, but this might need an edit.
plot(x = x, y = y, type = "l")
```

Finally, you can add the vertical and horizontal lines via the `abline()` function at the respective points.